# splitting a file into relevant sections in php

Tags: php, regex, process, split, logic

I have a config file that looks a bit like this

```
Blah
Diddel
Foo
Bar1
Bar2
One
XXY
Password%1 = something
Password%2 = other
Password%3 = nuffing
Completely different stuff here
RandomS6}=2
User%1 = Henry
User%2 = Marcus
User%3 = SecretAdmin
More stuff
Even more stuff
Loads of stuff
```

This is in a config.conf file that a user uploads via PHP form. I would like to read that file and create 5 new files out of it as follows:

1. All the lines from the beginning up to and including the line XXY
2. All the 'Password%...' lines
3. The lines between the last 'Password...' and the first 'User...' line
4. All the 'User...' lines
5. Everything underneath the 'User...' lines

Now the string matching I can handle, regex would be sweet but as it is a config with a strict format I can bodge it with

`while (substr($line,0,5) == "Passw" { ...`

What I can't get my head around is the structural way.
I started with nested if-loops but that a) strikes me as insanely inefficient (every line after the 'User...' block still gets tested for 'Password...') and b) not only does it look muddly it is also a nightmare to debug.

There must be a clever way to do this? I imagine it like dealing cards - "start at the deck, chuck cards into this pile until 'x' happens, then chuck cards into another pile until 'y' happens etc." but I am not enough of a programmer to get my head around it.

I have done a fair amount of googling and on here - but I get pages that tell me how to split on commas, or split by number of lines, but no tutorial to split semantically, as it were?

Most grateful for any hints!

P.S. - Does not have to be PHP if there is something much better suited to that role. But I am a beginner at Ruby and a baby at Python - PHP is what I know a little better than anything else.

Comment: The "dealing cards" algorithm you described can be easily implemented in Python using `itertools`. *(it isn't very complicated too with other languages)*.

Comment: itertools bookmarked. for this task the learning curve is too steep but it looks like it is worth investing some time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I chose, does sectionizing in four steps:

1. Match known `.conf` variables/delimiters and store them (Password,
       User, XXY)
2. Replace matched strings with nothing (omitting)
3. Split newly modified string into sections
4. Merge (1) and (3)

Here is the code:

```
$matches = [];
$string = preg_replace_callback(
        '~^(?>User.+|Password.+|XXY)$~m',
        function ($match) use (&$matches) {
            @$matches[substr($match[0], 0, 4)] .= $match[0];
            return null;
        },
        $input
    );

print_r(array_merge($matches, preg_split('/^\s+$/m', $string)));
```

Result is a little bit nasty and not totally in order (a bit more work to do it), but you have what you want (**[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/XikTm)**):

```
Array
(
    [XXY] => XXY

    [Pass] => Password%1 = something
Password%2 = other
Password%3 = nuffing

    [User] => User%1 = Henry
User%2 = Marcus
User%3 = SecretAdmin

    [0] => Blah
Diddel
Foo
Bar1
Bar2
One

    [1] => 
Completely different stuff here
RandomS6}=2

    [2] => 
More stuff
Even more stuff
Loads of stuff
)
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question you may mark it as accepted by clicking check mark icon. @sheepsky

Comment: took me a while to find it - now checked. Thanks again!